# Can I create a non-explicit constructor for a Java class?

Tags: java

By default, C++ will do "auto promotion" in assignment if appropriate constructors exist (and are not declared `explicit`).

In Java, this behavior doesn't happen by default.  If I want automatic promotion, is there a way to declare my constructors as implicit?

For example, here is some C++ code that has the effect that I want:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(string) { /* ... */ }
        /* Foo's methods and stuff */
};

void DoSomethingWithAFoo(Foo foo)
{
    /* ... */
}

int main()
{
    string s = "I am a happy string, I swear!";

    DoSomethingWithAFoo(s);    

    return 0;
}
```

Generally, in C++ this is allowed, and the `string s` will be automatically promoted (by constructing a temporary `Foo` from `s`).
Since the `Foo(string)` constructor is not marked explicit, I don't even need a typecast.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

I ask because I am trying to create a specific type that represents any one of a specific variety of other types.  For example, imagine a `class Primitive` that was representing either a single boolean, integer, character, or double (that's not my specific example, but it is related).

Methods in my system that expect a Primitive should also accept any of the "real types" that the Primitive might represent (by auto-promotion to an anonymous object of type Primitive through a constructor call).

In my actual work (as opposed to this example), my equivalent to the `Primitive` class has constructors both from a few primitive types as well as several object types (each constructor taking only the one parameter).  Ideally I would want auto promotion for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Java doesn't have implicit constructors.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think so, really, since all my searching turned up nothing.  But I did hope, because it would make the semantics of what I'm doing much nicer.

Comment: It's also a lot easier to do what you didn't mean to do when it makes assumptions on your behalf.  I've worked in C++ and lost much of my hair pulling it out when things like this went seriously wrong.

Comment: Alan, that is definitely possible.  It is why some other languages have reversed the situation and require implicit constructors to be marked as such.

But, in my case, my Java code will be full of someCall(new Foo(new Bar(someObject))); so I was hoping to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to construct it explicitely:

```
 DoSomethingWithAFoo(new Foo(s));
```